# How to select the second node using xsl:for-each in the listed xml content?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a list of figure names and width and height informations in separate xml file,

I need to match the figure name in the source xml file and need to insert the width and height information as a attribute in the source xml file.

here the source xml file..

```
<graphic name="sample.jpg" align="center"/>
```

expected output xml file

```
<graphic name="sample.jpg" width="100" depth="200" align="center"/>
```

figure measurement xml

```
<figure>
<name>sample.jpg</name>
<width>100</width>
<height>200</height>
</figure>
```

I have stored source file name attribute value in '$names'. And I have stored figure measure file name attribute value in '$figname'.

my xsl script

```
<xsl:for-each select="@name">
<xsl:if test="$figname=$name">
<xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="document('figure.xml')/figure/width"/></xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="depth"><xsl:value-of select="document('figure.xml')/figure/height"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It works for only the first time, not for all. i have nearly more than 100 images. for all images i need the width and height values. my scripts works only first value. how do i select the all value ?

plase suggest me..

Best Regards,
Antony

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I am sorry, i have used your scripts, but i am not able to get the exact output which i require.

I have given all the clear details here for your consideration.

INPUT XML:

```
<figure>
<title>Earliest Discoveries</title>
<graphic name="luc26959_0101.eps" align="center"/>
<caption>These lithographs of teeth of Iguanodon are from Mantell original 1825 article.</caption>
</figure>
```

INPUT FIGURE XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<figuregroup>
  <figure><name>luc26959_0101.eps</name><width>500</width><height>347</height></figure>
  <figure><name>luc26959_0102.eps</name><width>500</width><height>352</height></figure>
  <figure><name>luc26959_0103.eps</name><width>500</width><height>348</height></figure>
  <figure><name>luc26959_0104.eps</name><width>445</width><height>263</height></figure>
  <figure><name>luc26959_0105.eps</name><width>217</width><height>250</height></figure>
</figuregroup>
```

TRANSFORMATION XSL CODE:

```
<xsl:template match="graphic">
<xsl:variable name="names">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@name, '.')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:for-each select="//graphic">
    <imageobject>
        <imagedata>
        <xsl:attribute name="fileref">graphics/<xsl:value-of select="$names"/>.jpg</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="document('../input/fig.xml')/figuregroup/figure[name=$names]/width"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="depth"><xsl:value-of select="document('../input/fig.xml')/figuregroup/figure[name=$names]/height"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </imagedata>
     </imageobject>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT XML:

```
<figure>
<title>Earliest Discoveries</title>
<mediaobject>
    <imageobject><imagedata fileref="graphics/luc26959_0101.jpg" width="" depth=""/></imageobject>
    <imageobject><imagedata fileref="graphics/luc26959_0101.jpg" width="" depth=""/></imageobject>
    <imageobject><imagedata fileref="graphics/luc26959_0101.jpg" width="" depth=""/></imageobject>
    <imageobject><imagedata fileref="graphics/luc26959_0101.jpg" width="" depth=""/></imageobject>
    <imageobject><imagedata fileref="graphics/luc26959_0101.jpg" width="" depth=""/></imageobject>
    <caption><para>These lithographs of teeth of <emphasis>Iguanodon</emphasis> are from Mantell's original 1825 article.</para><para/></caption>
</mediaobject>
</figure>
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
<figure>
<title>Earliest Discoveries</title>
<mediaobject>
    <imageobject><imagedata fileref="graphics/luc26959_0101.jpg" width="500" depth="347"/></imageobject>
    <caption><para>These lithographs of teeth of <emphasis>Iguanodon</emphasis> are from Mantell's original 1825 article.</para><para/></caption>
</mediaobject>
</figure>
```

Hope i have given a clear picture about my requirement, i have tried with-out "for-each" also, when i give without 'for-each' i am not getting any output  element repeatly, only one time i m getting it, still width and depth attributes empty.

I dont know how to fill that attribute in the correct way, after using your code also.

Please help me..

Thanks & Regards,
Antony

Comment: See Markdown formatting for how to post code: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Take a look at my answer's most recent edit. I think it will contain your answer.

Comment: I can confirm Welbog's edited answer works, using the input given in the edited question.

Comment: So, a paleontologist who does XSLT? I should tell my sister, she'll like that, as her colleagues hardly know how to use Adobe CS, let alone LaTeX…

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of things wrong with your approach.

First of all, variables can only be assigned values once, and never again. I suspect that the code you're not showing us is assigning variables under the assumption that they are assigned more than once.

Secondly, `<for-each select="@name">` will only select one thing: the `name` attribute, if it is exists, in the current context. You probably want something more like `<for-each select="//graphic">` instead.

Then there's how you access `figure.xml` using the `document` function. Your example will only get the first height and width, regardless of the name of the image. You need to filter the results, using something like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="width">
  <xsl:value-of select="document('figure.xml')//figure[name=$name]/width"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Assuming you've set `$name` properly, which I covered in my first point.

You haven't given the entire troublesome XSLT snippet, so I can't give you a full correction. From what you have given me, though, I think you'll need to scrap what you have and re-evaluate your approach. What you're doing isn't complicated, but you're obviously new to XSLT and possibly functional programming as well. Here's an example to get you started:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//graphic">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- stuff to copy the attributes/children you want, left to the OP -->
      <xsl:attribute name="width">
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="document('figure.xml')//figure[name=$name]/width"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="height">
        <xsl:value-of 
          select="document('figure.xml')//figure[name=$name]/height"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**EDIT**

One thing I can safely say is that you really need to brush up on your [XSLT basics](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/). The problems you are experience are relatively simple, and mostly seem to stem from a belief that XSLT is smarter than it really is. That said, here is a script that I believe will cover what you need:

```
<xsl:template match="graphic">
  <!-- Get the name of the file in the right dir, with a .jpg extension -->
  <xsl:variable
    name="filename" 
    select="concat('graphics/',substring-before(@name, '.'),'.jpg')"
  />

  <!-- Set a variable to preserve the name of the file we're looking up -->
  <xsl:variable name="lookupname" select="@name"/>

  <!-- Look up this particular figure by name for easy access -->
  <xsl:variable
    name="lookup"
    select="document('../input/fig.xml')/figuregroup/figure[name=$lookupname]"
  />

  <imageobject>
    <imagedata>
    <xsl:attribute name="fileref">
      <xsl:value-of select="$filename"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <!-- Set the width and depth according to the lookup variable's children -->
    <xsl:attribute name="width">
      <xsl:value-of select="$lookup/width"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="depth">
      <xsl:value-of select="$lookup/height"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <!-- Apply any more templates as necessary -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </imagedata>
  </imageobject>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Just additional: if the data is in the *primary* input file, I'd look at using `xsl:key` to index them by name.

Comment: I'd avoid things like keys and recursive templates, Marc, because the OP is obviously new. I don't want to overwhelm him with new concepts, but rather apply ones he's already trying to use.

Comment: Obviously I'd welcome a more XSLT-spirited solution. Using loops in this situation rubs me the wrong way, but they're easier for people who are just getting into XSLT to understand.

Comment: @Welbog: This solution would gain if you would store the `document('figure.xml')//figure[name=$name]` in a variable first. Not only would overall readability increase, it would also be more efficient. Still +1 from me, and I agree to your "xsl:key" argument.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have an XML file with a lot of different elements and want to add the width and height to all the `<graphic...>` elements, without touching the rest of the XML. Am I correct? Then try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">    
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="graphic">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name"/>
  <xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/><xsl:attribute name="width">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('figure.xml')//figure[name=$name]/width"/>
  </xsl:attribute><xsl:attribute name="height">
    <xsl:value-of select="document('figure.xml')//figure[name=$name]/height"/>
  </xsl:attribute></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I used the attribute lookup code that Welbog suggested, so make sure you upvote him.

It copies all elements and attributes as-is (unless I made a mistake) but treats `<graphic...>` elements specially by also adding the width and height as looked-up in the `figure.xml` file. Add more templates if you want to treat other elements specially, or omit them.

Comment: Uh... can you indent that correctly? Horizontal scrolling sucks more than vertical scrolling.

Comment: OK, sorry. But I had to stick the tags inside <xsl:copy> because otherwise it takes the line breaks as content and then refuses to add attributes. I forgot if there's a way to prevent it.

Comment: Put the xsl:attribute elements before the xsl:copy-of element.  Also, that's not the canonical identity transform you've got going on there; it won't copy comments or processing instructions or CDATA sections.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Robert. My XSLT is a bit rusted, it's always helpful.